# Python script audibly represents itself

Tags: python, audio

I was just messing around with python making `wav` files; when I came up with this (what I think is) pretty neat script. It takes each character and represents it with a tone.

```
import wave
import struct
from math import sin
import os

RATE = 44100
maxVol = 2 ** 15 - 1.0  # maximum amplitude

noise_output = wave.open('noise2.wav', 'w')
noise_output.setparams((2, 2, 44100, 0, 'NONE', 'not compressed'))

a = lambda i, f: sin(f * i / RATE)
f = open(os.path.basename(__file__)).read()
values = [[a, (ord(l))] for l in f]
result = []
count = 0

for i, j in values:
    count_end = count + RATE / 8
    while count < count_end:
        packed_value = struct.pack('h', maxVol * i(count, j * 20 + 1000))
        result.append(packed_value)
        result.append(packed_value)
        count += 1

result_str = ''.join(result)
noise_output.writeframes(result_str)

noise_output.close()
```

I found the original [here](http://www.swharden.com/blog/2011-07-08-create-mono-and-stereo-wave-files-with-python/). The original just makes a constant tone. Runs fine with Python 3. I would love to see a decoder for this; but I don't know enough about calculating frequencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You should not use single letter variables.
- Rather than a lambda you can create an actual function and pass its name.
- There are still several magic numbers. What is 8, 20, etc.?
- `maxVol` should also be uppercase, and should probably be named `MAXIMUM_AMPLITUDE` to avoid the need for the comment.
- Rather than duplicating `result.append` you can use a separate function with a counter for how many times you want to repeat it.
- Encapsulate functionality in functions or objects. Initialising `noise_output` (or the output as an object), the `for` loop and outputting/closing the stream are candidates.
- Check whether it's possible to use `with wave.open('noise2.wav', 'w') as noise_output:` or similar.
- Rather than reading the whole file into memory you can read a chunk at a time to speed up the program.
- Some variable names are difficult to understand. `values` is almost meaningless (all it tells me is that it's an array-like structure), `results` likewise (how about something like `audio_bytes`?).